# Create a list of values from an existing list if values are nearby

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries

```
[{"Name": 'A', "Area": 10000, "Price": 100}, 
{"Name": 'B', "Area": 9500, "Price": 99},
{"Name": 'C', "Area": 11000, "Price": 101},
{"Name": 'D', "Area": 12000, "Price": 150}
{"Name": 'E', "Area": 14000, "Price": 200},
{"Name": 'F', "Area": 14500, "Price": 400},
{"Name": 'G', "Area": 12999, "Price": 159}]
```

I'd like to create 2 new lists of dictionaries based on the two threshold criteria on *Area* and *Price* key. At this example the threshold I use is 1000 for *Area* and 10 for *Price*, so I'm expecting to receive 2 lists:

Possible duplicates which follow the threshold:

```
[{"Name": 'A', "Area": 10000, "Price": 100},    #Because it is less than 1000 in Area and less than 10 in Price for B and C items
{"Name": 'B', "Area": 9500, "Price": 99},    #For A and C 
{"Name": 'C', "Area": 11000, "Price": 101},    #For A and B
{"Name": 'D', "Area": 12000, "Price": 150},    #For G, but not for C because the price difference is more than 10
{"Name": 'G', "Area": 12999, "Price": 159}]    #For D
```

The remaining items from original list of dicts which were not selected as duplicates

```
[{"Name": 'E', "Area": 14000, "Price": 200},    #Not selected because the price difference is more than 10
{"Name": 'F', "Area": 14500, "Price": 400}    #The same
```

The only idea, which comes to my mind is the naive solution to perform 2 loops for the each list to compare the *Area* and *Price* values with others. I am sure there is more *pythonic* way of the solution

Comment: This line will check if the area of a dictionary is within threshold of the next dictionary. It only checks the next dictionary in the list, so it doesn't solve your problem but hopefully gives you an idea of what you could do.
`dicts_range = range(0, len(dicts) - 1)`
`k = [dicts[i] if(-1000 <= dicts[i]["Area"] - dicts[i+1]["Area"] <= 1000) else 1+1 for i in dicts_range]`

Comment: The `else 1+1` is just there because it wasn't letting me to `else continue`

Comment: Checking both price and area:
`k = [dicts[i] if((-1000 <= dicts[i]["Area"] - dicts[i+1]["Area"] <= 1000) and (-10 <= dicts[i]["Price"] - dicts[i+1]["Price"] <= 10)) else 1+1 for i in dicts_range]`

Answer (score 1):

Setup:

```py
apData = [{"Name": 'A', "Area": 10000, "Price": 100}, {"Name": 'B', "Area": 9500, "Price": 99}, {"Name": 'C', "Area": 11000, "Price": 101}, {"Name": 'D', "Area": 12000, "Price": 150}, {"Name": 'E', "Area": 14000, "Price": 200}, {"Name": 'F', "Area": 14500, "Price": 400}, {"Name": 'G', "Area": 12999, "Price": 159}]

threshRef = {'Area':1000, 'Price':10}
ck_margins = lambda c,n: all(abs(n[k]-c[k])<=threshRef[k] for k in threshRef)
```

`threshRef` should contain all the thresholds, and `ck_margins` is for checking if 2 dictionaries are within each other's thresholds as specified in `threshRef` (if the logic is more complicated, you might have to define a function instead of just using a [lambda expression](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/anonymous-function)).

---

> *The only idea, which comes to my mind is the naive solution to perform 2 loops for the each list to compare the Area and Price values with others.*

That *is* the simplest way to do it - some variation of the code below, which checks each item against every other item [ [time complexity](https://blog.teclado.com/time-complexity-big-o-notation-python/): <kbd>[**O(n<sup>2</sup>)**](https://blog.teclado.com/time-complexity-big-o-notation-python/#6on2polynomialtime)</kbd> ].

```py
selected, unselected = [], []
for i, cur in enumerate(apData):
    selectCur = any(ck_margins(cur,d) for di,d in enumerate(apData) if di!=i) 
    (selected if selectCur else unselected).append(cur)
```

You could improve on it a bit by stopping as soon as you reach the first item that matches the criteria [since you only need one match]; then the time complexity could still be <kbd>O(n<sup>2</sup>)</kbd> in the worst case [if none of them were to be selected], but in the best case [sorted list where all of them get selected] it could be as low as <kbd>O(n)</kbd> [linear].

```py
selected, unselected = [], []
for i, cur in enumerate(apData):
    selectCur = False
    for di, d in enumerate(apData):
        if di!=i and ck_margins(cur,d):
            selectCur = True
            break
    (selected if selectCur else unselected).append(cur)
```

Or you could only check each item against every item that comes *after* it in the list, so that no combination gets checked more than once [time complexity: <kbd>[**<sub>n</sub>C<sub>2</sub>**](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/discretemathematics/combinations.php)</kbd>].

```py
selected, unselected, hasNeighbor = [], [], [False]*len(apData)

for i1, d1 in enumerate(apData):
    for i2, d2 in enumerate(apData[i1+1:], i1+1):
        if ck_margins(d1,d2): hasNeighbor[i1] = hasNeighbor[i2] = True

for cur, selectCur in zip(apData,hasNeighbor): 
    (selected if selectCur else unselected).append(cur)
```

---

#### Suggestion: Iterate through Sorted List

Since you need *both* price and area to be within thresholds, if you sort the list by those fields, then you'll only need to check against the [items before and after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JO3v.png) as you go down the sorted list <sup>([view results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWUPi.png))</sup> [time complexity: <kbd>[**O(n*log<sub>2</sub>n)**](https://realpython.com/sorting-algorithms-python/#measuring-merge-sorts-big-o-complexity)</kbd>].

```py
apSorted = sorted(apData, key=lambda d: [d[k] for k in threshRef])

selected, unselected = [], []
for prev, cur, nxt in zip([{}]+apSorted[:-1], apSorted, apSorted[1:]+[{}]):
    selectCur = any(ck_margins(cur, x) for x in [prev, nxt] if x)
    (selected if selectCur else unselected).append(cur)
```

This would be my preferred way to do it as long as I didn't care about the original order of the list [restoring that would require sorting yet again if this method is used].

[It doesn't matter much unless your list is very large, but] it would use up less memory if you iterated through indices (instead of [zipping](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) shifted copies together):

```py
ap_sort_pad = [{}] + sorted(apData, key=lambda d: [d[k] for k in threshRef]) + [{}]

selected, unselected = [], []
for i in range(len(ap_sort_pad)-2):
    prev, cur, nxt = ap_sort_pad[i:i+3]
    selectCur = any(ck_margins(cur, x) for x in [prev, nxt] if x)
    (selected if selectCur else unselected).append(cur)
```